# Extracting a URL from a string in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, url

I have a string like

```
<dd>TF-AIDN, "Proposal for something...", Version 3.4, 18 November 2015 https://www.something.org/en/system/files/files/file-18nov15-en.pdf</dd>
```

How can I modify the following statement to extract URL from such a string?

```
urlfinder = re.compile(r"((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)", re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)
```

I am not able to figure out how can I modify the regular expression so that it takes `<` as the end mark of a URL instead of a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex instead:

```
(http[^<]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iGEPn4/1)**

This will match a pattern having http and everything but `<`